# Will log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG with no appender on that level impact in performance?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Lets imagine a scenario A where I have log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG and a file appender with the same logging level:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, default.out, default.file 

log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=log/error.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.default.file.MaxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.default.file.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Now we gonna compare with scenario B:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, default.out, default.file 

log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=log/error.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.MaxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.default.file.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I know that scenario A will be a lot more verbose than B, impacting a log in my software performance. But now, lets compare with another scenario C where I put the rootLogger to DEBUG but my appender to INFO:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, default.out, default.file 

log4j.appender.default.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.default.file.append=true
log4j.appender.default.file.file=log/error.log
log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.default.file.MaxFileSize=10240KB
log4j.appender.default.file.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.default.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

My file created by log4j will not be written with a lot  of information from DEBUG logger, because I set `log4j.appender.default.file.threshold=INFO`, so only INFO will be written. But how about my rootLogger set on DEBUG?

Will `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG` make a impact in performance? Will scneario B be more efficient than scnario C?

Answer (score 1):

Scenario B will be a bit better than Scenario C.

The most slow down comes from writing the logs to the file by the appender. That impact is the same in both scenarios.
But there is also a slow down in the execution by the logger even without any appender, as you need to execute the code for each log message to check for the current appenders when the logger has passed the log level for the current message. This will more often happen in Scenario C.

Also in some code the creation of expensive log messages is guarded by checking the log level first. In Scenario C this code is still executed, while in Scenario B it is skipped and the execution is faster e.g.:

```
if(logger.isEnabledFor(Level.DEBUG)) {
    logger.debug("message: " + object.expensiveToString())
}
```